# Graphically intensive silverlight design

Tags: c#, web-applications

I'm designing a silverlight application for showing sheet music from a midi file.

I want to create a horizontally scrolling musical staff.

At my job I maintain a winforms application that is a scrolling Gantt chart of airplane schedules, and it basically has a rows collection, and it maps the left-most pixel and right-most pixels of the control to datetimes. Then the paint method loops through what it determines will be the visible rows, and draws a screen that shows the schedule information between the two dates.

Would I be correct in assuming that I would need to something similar in silverlight for my sheetmusic, or would it be better to just create a horizontal scrollviewer containing a canvas that I have drawn programmaticially on.

Am I headed in the right direction? I havent seen any articles on designing such a custom control: can you point me at any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think your second idea - that of a horizontal scroll viewer is the "better" one.

With Silverlight, unless you get into the really low level drawing of 3D elements, you don't need (or indeed have) the same concept as a "paint" method.

It might even be worth looking at a horizontal `StackPanel` with a background image of the staves. Then each element in the panel could be a note (or a collection of notes) that would draw themselves.